# Conteo de registros en SQL en Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

Cordial saludo equipo, les escribe Hernán Martínez desde Colombia, deseo pedirlesel favor con lo siguiente, tengo la siguiente consulta en Access, la cual me trae unos registros:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CausalesSemana28.Descripcion) AS Causal, CausalesSemana28.Franja
FROM CausalesSemana28
WHERE (((CausalesSemana28.ZONA)="Calle 80") AND ((CausalesSemana28.RUTA)="621"))
GROUP BY (CausalesSemana28.Descripcion), CausalesSemana28.Franja;
```

Necesito crear un campo a la izquierda el cual me traiga el numero de registros de CausalesSemana28.Descripcion.

Muchas gracias!.

Comment: Si estás haciendo esto en Access, mira la función [método Application.DCount (Access)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.application.dcount). Podrás contar cuántos registros de cada tipo según esa consulta agrupada, Posiblemente esta cuenta tengas que hacerlo en una secundaria. No sé si en este GROUPBY podrías simplemente añadir un COUNT. Si facilitas un ejemplo de datos sencillo, con el input y el output esperado quizás se puedan hacer pruebas.